# Get values from jquery dropdown select

Tags: php, html

I want to use this script for dropdown select list
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/
I want to use example(demo) 3.
but I can't get selected value with PHP.
Can you help ?

Comment: can you post your php code, or explain what do you want exactly ?

Comment: I tried this
<form method="get" action="test2.php">
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
<span>Please, fill...</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
       <li><a href="#">Classic mail</a></li>
<input id="getvalue" name="getvalue" type="hidden" value="Classic mail"/> 
<li><a href="#">UPS Delivery</a></li>
       <input id="getvalue" name="getvalue" type="hidden" value="UPS Delivery"/> 
       <li><a href="#">Private jet</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <input type="submit">
     </form>

And in test2.php :
<?php
$getvalue = $_GET['getvalue'];
echo $getvalue;
?>

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking forward for something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Test
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <?php
            if(is_array($your_drop_down_list)&&!empty($your_drop_down_list))
                foreach($your_drop_down_list as $item)
                {
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $item['item_link'] ?>"><a class="<?php echo $item['item_class'] ?> icon-large"><?php echo $item['item_title'] ?></a></li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This script never use an input , so you can't directly get the value with php.

You should use a hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="jscombo" value="" />` and change its value when the user select something new in the list.

You maybe should try something else like [Dropkick](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) which use a real input

Comment: How I can change it's value when the user select something new in the list ?
I can't work with javascript... it's difficult for me

Comment: Simply add an event on the <a> click. It's already done in the article , you just have to change the value of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=getvalue]').change(function(){
           $('#hidden_field').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Also, add a hidden field,

```
    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_field' id='hidden_field' />
```

And, on test2.php, change,

```
       $getvalue = $_GET['hidden_field'];
```